# IEC 60664-1 clearance between phase and earth

Tags: ac, three-phase, clearance, iec

With IEC 60664-1 you require clearance between phase and earth.

But if you have a resistor voltage divider between phase and earth do you need the same clearance between the pads of the resistors?

Or is it strictly between Phase and Earth copper?

I mean technically if there is a voltage divider then phase and earth are connected but with resistance... By that logic, technically even a trace has resistance.

Am I missing something?

Comment: You're using more than 1 resistor right?

Comment: Yeah 3 resistors in series